# How to replace blocks and items in Minecraft .mca files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to turn `.mca` files into a human readable format? Is there a way to replace all of a certain block or item in a `.mca` file?

I would like to replace all instances of a modded block with a vanilla block. I plan on updating my Minecraft java modded world into a newer version, but the newer versions of a mod removes some blocks and items.

I would also like to replace items in inventories and storage and biomes too.

I tried opening `.mca` files in a text editor, but that just gave me a bunch of symbols. Where do I get started? Are those files zipped or something?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I'm not looking for recommendations. I'm looking for a way to modify game files. Would stackoverflow be a better place?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 This question is not asking for a tool ("If there isn't, I don't mind doing some programming myself.") , and questions about game file formats [are on-topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12915/185203)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 It's not mod development. .mca are minecraft world save files. mca files are used by the vanilla game though mods can also use them.

Comment: @PerfectFiasco Right, that makes things more clear. Thanks for editing your question to clarify your intent, so that others don't make the same assumption I did!

Comment: Uhhh... Isn't this a modding question? I'm pretty sure the average player shouldn't know how to programmatically manipulate NBT.

Answer (score 8):

One of the most common tools for editing Minecraft files is [NBT Explorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer).

It doesn't do what you need, but since you mentioned you can program it yourself here are some pointers:

The `.mca` file format is called [Anvil file format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil_file_format) and is based on [Region file format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Region_file_format) with changes to the chunk format. The description in the wiki is not very friendly but basically, to read anvil files:

- Follow [Region file format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Region_file_format) until you get the chunk blobs.
- Once you decompress the blob, it is in [Named Binary Tag format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format) which is a generic binary format.
- Once you can parse the NBT tags, consult [Chunk format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format) to interpret the chunk data.

NBT Explorer is open source, so you'll be able to borrow some code from there, specifically [this part](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer/tree/master/NBTModel/Data) seems to be concerned with the actual parsing and interpreting of the data.

Comment: Here’s another somewhat-more-useful reference on locating chunks in region files: https://wiki.vg/Region_Files

Answer (score 3):

If manually [going through NBT Data](https://wiki.vg/NBT) is not your thing, you can use editors such as:

- [MCEdit](https://mcedit.net)
- WorldEdit ([Forge](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/worldedit) [Sponge/Bukkit/Spigot](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldedit))

And mass-editing the world in-game instead. There's also the [`/fill`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill) command.

Edit: [This may be what you're looking for](https://github.com/Querz/mcaselector)

Comment: I'm trying to edit a modded world, but the process should be same for vanilla and modded. For instance, I might want to replace all grass blocks with podzol. At least, I hope it's that way. WorldEdit wouldn't work because I need to do search and replace in all generated chunks.

Comment: WorldEdit has mod support, don't worry.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I also want to replace all of a specified item, whether it's in a player inventory or chests. I don't think WorldEdit can do that.