# How to extract sign text from .mca file in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am writing a script that locates all the signs in my old multiplayer Minecraft world save. I want to retrieve text on these signs and store/present it somewhere.

I am leveraging [anvil parser](https://anvil-parser.readthedocs.io) to find where signs actually are in the region's chunk - and I get all the way up to the point where I have the sign [block instance](https://anvil-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#block) available. When I print out the `properties`, I get only `waterlogged` and `rotation` information.

Where is the actual text stored in the `.mca` file? And what would be the best way to access it give I currently have only block's local coordinates (meaning it's coordinates within the chunk it is located in)?

Note that this is not meant to be "looking for support for this parser I use". I know that there are people on this exchange [who are familiar with](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/375198) `.mca` and `nbt` format, who could provide me insight into where and how to look for this kind of information. While I referenced the specific parser to give provide sufficient context, I am open to using just about any approach/technology to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the sign is stored in a [Block entity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_entity) (also called a tile entity), rather than as part of the block state. Looking at the [source code for your parser](https://github.com/matcool/anvil-parser/blob/master/anvil/chunk.py), you can access the contents of the block entity by calling the `get_tile_entity(x, y, z)`. (This does mean that I don't think there is a way of getting the tile entity only knowing it's chunk-local coordinates, since tile entities are identified in the MCA file by their global coordinates)

Once you have found the relevant block entity, the text of the sign is it's `Text1` through `Text4` properties, in JSON format.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Shortly after the question was posted, I discovered that there are tile entities attached to each chunk, then got back here and you already provided me with an answer!